# retrieved URLs, trouble building payload to use requests module

Tags: python

I'm a Python novice, thanks for your patience.

I retrieved a web page, using the requests module. I used Beautiful Soup to harvest a few hundred href objects (links). I used uritools to create an array of full URLs for the target pages I want to download.

I don't want everybody who reads this note to bombard the web server with requests, so I'll show a hypothetical example that is realistic for just 2 hrefs. The array looks like this:

```
hrefs2 = ['http://ku.edu/pls/WP040?PT001F01=910&pf7331=11',
 'http://ku.edu/pls/WP040?PT001F01=910&pf7331=12']
```

If I were typing these into 100s of lines of code, I understand what to do in order to retrieve each page:

```
from lxml import html
import requests

url = 'http://ku.edu/pls/WP040/'
payload = {'PT001F01' : '910', 'pf7331' : '11')

r = requests.get(url, params = payload)
```

Then get the second page

```
payload = {'PT001F01' : '910', 'pf7331' : '12')
r = requests.get(url, params = payload)
```

And keep typing in payload objects. Not all of the hrefs I'm dealing with are sequential, not all of the payloads are different simply in the last integer.

I want to automate this and I don't see how to create the payloads from the hrefs2 array.

While fiddling with uritools, I find `urisplit` which can give me the part I need to parse into a payload:

```
   [urisplit(x)[3] for x in hrefs2] 

   ['PT001F01=910&pf7331=11',
     'PT001F01=910&pf7331=12']
```

Each one of those has to be turned into a payload object and I don't understand what to do.

I'm using Python3 and I used uritools because that appears to be the standards-compliant replacement of urltools.

I fell back on shell script to get pages with `wget`, which does work, but it is so un-Python-ish that I'm asking here for what to do.  I mean, this does work:

```
import subprocess

for i in hrefs2:   
    subprocess.call(["wget", i])
```

Comment: I don't understand why you can't use `requests.get` instead of the subprocess call to wget in the last bit of code. Where are you stuck?

Comment: From the manual from requests.get, I thought I was required to separate the part of the url after ? into a payload.  I see now I was just wrong and can do as you suggest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass the full url to requests.get() without splitting up the parameters.

```
>>> requests.get('http://ku.edu/pls/WP040?PT001F01=910&pf7331=12')
<Response [200]>
```

If for some reason you don't want to do that, you'll need to split up the parameters some how.  I'm sure there are better ways to do it, but the first thing that comes to mind is:

```
a = ['PT001F01=910&pf7331=11',
    'PT001F01=910&pf7331=12']
# list to store all url parameters after they're converted to dicts
urldata = []

#iterate over list of params
for param in a:
  data = {}
  # split the string into key value pairs
  for kv in param.split('&'):
    # split the pairs up
    b = kv.split('=')
    # first part is the key, second is the value
    data[b[0]] = b[1]
  # After converting every kv pair in the parameter, add the result to a list.
  urldata.append(data)
```

You could do this with less code but I wanted to be clear what was going on.  I'm sure there is already a module somewhere out there that does this for you too.

Comment: @Daniel Roseman suggested same. get.request will accept full URL with flags. I misunderstood instructions for get.request()